# The conditions to determine whether multivector $\Lambda\in\wedge^k V$ is decomposable

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, grassmannians, multilinear-algebra

In Section 5, Chapter 1 of the famous book "Principles of algebraic geometry" by Griffiths and Harris, there are two equivalent conditions to determine whether a multivector $\Lambda\in\wedge ^kV$ is decomposable. One is given by $i(i(\Xi)\Lambda)\Lambda=0$ for all $\Xi\in\wedge^{k+1}V^*$, while another is $(i(\Xi)\Lambda)\wedge \Lambda=0$ for all $\Xi\in\wedge^{k-1}V^*$. I can understand the first one. But I do not understand the second one.  The major difficulty for me is given as follows.

Denote $W=Ann(\Lambda^\perp)$ and $\Lambda^\perp=\{v^*\in V^*|i(v^*)\Lambda=0\}$. Then it is stated that $W$ is the image of $$\wedge^{k-1}V^*\rightarrow V$$ under the map
$$\Xi\rightarrow i(\Xi)\Lambda,\quad \Xi\in\wedge^{k-1}V^*.$$
My question is how to understand this statement.

I know $i(\Xi)\Lambda\in W$ for $\Xi\in\wedge^{k-1}V^*$. So if denote $U=\{i(\Xi)\Lambda|\Xi\in\wedge^{k-1}V^*\}$, then $U\subset W$. If one can prove $\Lambda\in \wedge^k U$, then by the fact $W$ is the minimal subspace $\widetilde{W}$ of $V$ such that $\Lambda\in \wedge^k\widetilde{W}$, which can also be found in Chapter 1, Section 5 of Griffiths and Harris's book.  So the remaining question is how to prove $\Lambda\in \wedge^k U$. But I find it is very difficult. Could anyone can help me? I will thank you very much.